# Identify if server boots using upstart or sysvinit

Tags: linux, upstart

I am a not a experienced linux user/admin, but last week I acquired a raspberry, and installed on it a Raspbmc, based on Debian distro.

I am having some troubles trying to identify which scripts the distro is using for services, I know that there are the init.d scripts determined on specific runlevels (rc0.d, rc1.d etc..)

And I must state that I am a bit confused about it.

My question is, when I have init .conf files for upstart, the rc0123456.d files still are valid ? the boot respects only one at time (upstart or sysvinit) or both at same time?

And how can I identify which one is being used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On debian, you will have sysv scripts, Upstart jobs, and systemd services all installed at once. With Upstart and systemd, the jobs/services will be used if available, and the sysv scripts will be run if no Upstart or systemd jobs/services are available.

This command returning success means Upstart was booted:

```
test -x /sbin/initctl && /sbin/initctl --version | grep -q upstart || false
```

This command returning success means systemd was booted:

```
test -d /run/systemd/system
```

Otherwise, you are on sysvinit.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case for wanderers:
You can identify which init system is being used by using this command:
`ps 1 | awk '/1/{print $5;}'`
Otherwise, you can mistake any init system for sysv =)